# Pass list of json to javascript in jinja template flask (python)

Tags: javascript, python, list, flask, jinja2

I have a list of dictionary. How can I pass this list to the javascript function using this list?

```
list_of_keys = []
list_of_connections = []

@app.route("/", methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def hello():
    form = SignupForm()
    val = False
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():      
         #print(UPLOADS_PATH)
         #print("sakshi")
         adlsgraph(str(form.adlsname1.data),str(form.adlsname2.data))
         print(list_of_keys)
         print(list_of_connections)
         lis1 = {"list_of_keys":list_of_keys, 
         "list_of_connections":list_of_connections}
         lis=json.dumps(lis1)
         print(lis)
         return redirect(url_for('.hello', lis=list_of_keys, _anchor="services")) 
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, val=val, lis=list_of_keys)
```

In flask template,
    `{{ lis|tojson|safe }}`

Output shows the empty list -

```
"\"{}\""
```

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far and a concrete input example and expected result. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: added the code..please have a look

Answer (score 0):

In the view function `hello` you did not do anything to `list_of_keys`, that's why it's an empty list in template.